# What if a bogus suggested edit was credited to you?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, review-audits

It seems audit suggested edits are credited to real users<sup>1</sup>. For example, I was recently presented with [two](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1565637) [audits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1565664); coincidently, I rejected an [apparently legit edit suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1552679) by [the same user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2086034/user2086034?tab=activity) yesterday. That made me think, what if one of those nonsense edits were attributed to *my* user? At first, I thought I wouldn't like it ("how could such an atrocity be linked to my user?!"). But then I remembered such suggestions are clearly marked as audits, and thought it could be actually funny to have one of those credited to me.

What do *you* think? Would you like to be the "author" of poetry such as "I have an array of background images that sent and returned interlocked"?

<sub>(1) If that's not the case, please let me know, and I'll delete this question</sub>

Comment: Aren't close/reopen audits also "credited" to real users?

Comment: I don't know; actually, I never thought about that before noticing those suggested edits (which are funnier than audits from other queues).

Comment: Obviously these should all be attributed to [random](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/9314/random).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "credited to you"? If the edit gets approved by a couple of votes, it gets credited to the one who suggested it; the audit votes themselves are "credited" to you of course.

Comment: @Jack the question is about bogus suggested edits created for audits, which are attributed to real users, even though they are not real edits.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Oh I see, those that are meant to keep auditors on their toes? :)

Comment: @Jack The "auditor" in this case is the system, auditing our job reviewing suggested edits.

Comment: @Jack Right; I didn't realize what this was about until I saw psubsee's comment, either!

Comment: Time for some Fraley http://www.fraleyfacebooksettlement.com/

Comment: @sixlettervariables But that's not random!

Comment: I thought [that's whats the wheel of blame is for](http://jsfiddle.net/badp/zmV5w/37/embedded/result/)?

Comment: I for one would probably be proud to participate in fighting **[meta-tag:review-abuse]** - anything I can help, I'd give it, including attribution like this (consider this as an official volunteering confirmation)

Comment: Someone just got a mod message because of a review audit credited to them. This is a real problem.

Comment: @mmyers Maybe you could point said user to this meta-discussion? My question was hypothetical, and having an actual case being discussed here would be nice.

Comment: Meta post about the incident mmyers mentions: [Stop using real accounts in suggested edit audits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170683)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suggested edit audits are randomized, not just when presented to you at review, but when viewed by others later on. For example, the audits you link above are not attributed to user2086034 when I look at them now, but instead to Erwin van Ekeren and razor-sharp. Others looking at them tomorrow may see different users. Try looking at these again yourself and see if the authors and content have changed.

I don't believe there's any risk of long-term association with a particular audit example, unless you happened to take a screenshot of it.

Comment: True, now I'm seeing the same users you mentioned. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 9):

I'm assuming that it also only attributes these fake edits to users who can still suggest them anyways (i.e. less than 2,000 reputation). I don't always pay attention to the user, but as far as I can recall they've all been attributed to very low-rep users whom are probably not even familiar with the review system or the fact that audits even exist.

That being said, those audits only show up in two places:

- The history tab of the suggested edits review task, for users with 10,000 reputation
- Your activity history under the **reviews** tab

The key thing here, they *don't* show up in that user's activity, and they're pretty well hidden from anyone who isn't explicitly searching through review histories looking for audits.

I do like this functionality for the actual audit. I think randomly generating names and "fake profiles" to assist suggested edits would be overly complicated and more noticeable that it's an audit.

**However**, that random name that was selected shouldn't remain on the audit after it has been completed. Once it's completed, the name should be removed, or the edit should be attributed to the Community user ([or random](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168396/what-if-a-bogus-suggested-edit-was-credited-to-you#comment496158_168396)), just so that people who *do* happen upon it... by chance... in the future... aren't completely confused. This would be similar to how the Low Quality Posts task shows you the *actual* current state of the post once you've completed an audit and look back on it, even though the screen you saw previously didn't look like that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the purpose of doing so is to prevent people auto-accepting. I've done it sometimes as well, where I notice that the suggester is user X and I just approve it without thoroughly reading the suggest. I don't do that anymore, but others may.

The only caveat here is that mods get confused by audits. If you see too many of these coming from the same user, you feel like mod messaging them (almost happened with another mod).  I'm not sure what exactly happens when you get a review audit, but if the system isn't doing so already, it should always display the "Congrats, you passed" message if you pass an audit.

Comment: The system doesn't say "Congrats" on the suggested edits queue, it just takes you to the next post. You have to go back to check manually. Other queues do make it clear it was an audit after you pass, IIRC.

Comment: @bfavaretto: Yep, then that should be a feature-request.