# Review testing questions are too obvious

Tags: feature-request, review, review-audits

I was reviewing today and noticed a couple of tests, I knew they were tests because Community raised them.

The tests are great and I agree 100% with "kicking blatant abusers out of the queues automatically" as per https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/review-suspension/info

Is it possible to camouflage these tests by hiding Community? The tests would be better if  they were disguised and came from real users (who have generously written some tests)?

Comment: Dunno why, but I've always(>=80% times) failed those audits. :-/

Comment: I'm up for writing some bad questions and answers if moderators want it. I'm usually constantly refreshing the review page anyway just to have something to do.

Comment: I don't think people whom these tests are made for will notice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [Stop using real accounts in suggested edit audits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170683/stop-using-real-accounts-in-suggested-edit-audits)

Suggested edit audits are special. During the audit, the edit will be (falsely) attributed to a random user on the site. Once the audit is passed or failed, the user is replaced with the Community user so that the reviewer isn't confused into berating the random user (who has no clue that the system is impersonating him)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I think I made a mistake.

I was reviewing again and *what I believe I saw* was Community is only revealed once you pass the test.

I cant go back (browser back button) to confirm.