# Apparent moderator script vandalizes post

Tags: discussion, review-audits, vandalism, automatic-edits

This edit https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3819037 was apparently done by a moderator user named ["Community"](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) and appears to be robot vandalism.

> I can T written ints 1 documentcomplete handler am

What is it?

comment says "this is easy to do on linux"

Comment: See [Who is the Community user?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19738/135887) and [Stop using real accounts in suggested edit audits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170683/135887) and [What are review tests (audits) and how do they work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157121/135887)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a review audit:

[image]

Further reading:

- [What are review tests (audits) and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work)
- [Who is the Community user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user)
- [Stop using real accounts in suggested edit audits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170683/stop-using-real-accounts-in-suggested-edit-audits) (explains why Community takes responsibillity for the edit, once the audit is over)

Comment: So? the nominal user is a moderator.  Why would anonymous users have the power to do this?

Comment: Read the links Yannis provided.

Comment: @AlexBrown It's not a real edit, just a test. And Community is a bot, not a real moderator.

Comment: Wow.  I thought I got enough periodic reviews at work - I need them here too? :-)

Comment: @AlexBrown Unfortunately, yes. Too many people abused the review system to earn cheap badges, and spoiled the fun for everyone.

Comment: @AlexBrown: http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/3810382 suggests you need more than you're getting. That question really looks good to you? *boggles*

Comment: I'm required to use my judgement.  If I wasn't, we would use a robot.  I read elsewhere on meta the opinion that *surfacing hidden documentation or resources* was an appropriate role (this was an opinion, not a rule), and to me this post did not qualify for the given close reason, since it was not asking for 'recommendations' or 'opinions', but a fact.  Remember, I'm not raising a close, I'm judging whether the given close reason matches the post.